# webmethod is not fired

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webmethod

My first attempt to get a server side function called from javascript is not working as the webmethod is not getting called.

The aspx file contains a bootstrap styled button; when clicked, I need to add a record to user's "Favorites" list (add a record in database).

The page inherits from a master page and master page contains:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

aspx page has:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addFavorite(url, friendly) {debugger
    PageMethods.AddFavorite(url, friendly, onSuccess);
}
function onSuccess(result, userContext, methodName) {debugger
    alert(result);
}
</script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="addFavorite('some_url', 'some firendly name');">
<i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Favorites</button>
```

In code behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string AddFavorite(string sURL, string sFriendlyName)
{
    // This is where I would add a record to a DB table, but for testing ...
    return sFriendlyName;
}
```

When I click the button, it hits addFavorites() and immediately onSuccess and bypasses web method, it hen displays the page source on an alert box (partially of course).

I have searched and can't seem to know what I am doing wrong. All examples show the same steps I have taken.

Comment: I have just copy code and your method it is working fine  use below config might be it will help you  <system.webServer>     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>  </system.webServer>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could repro this on my local machine. Noticed that the script module was not registered in the **modules** section in the **web.config**!

Make sure you include the script module as follows in your web.config to make it work:

```
<system.webServer>
          <modules>
           <!-- *...other registered modules..* -->
           <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
           </modules>
    </system.webServer>
```

**Update**

Make sure you have FriendlyUrlSettings.AutoRedirectMode  set to Off, otherwise the page method request would return 401 UnAuthorized. The code should be set as follows in the RouteConfig:

```
public static class RouteConfig  
{  
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)  
    {  
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();  
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;  
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);  
    }  
}
```

In case you want to retain the Friendly URLs, then add your own friendly url resolver that inherits from WebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver as follows:

```
public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings, new WebMethodFriendlyUrlResolver());
    }
}

public class WebMethodFriendlyUrlResolver : WebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver
{
    public override string ConvertToFriendlyUrl(string path)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.PathInfo != string.Empty)
        {
            return path;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.ConvertToFriendlyUrl(path);
        }
    }
}
```

If friendly URL is enabled, JavaScript callback function must be updated to set the path to include the .aspx extension explicitly:

```
function addFavorite(url, friendly) {  
        PageMethods.set_path(PageMethods.get_path() + '.aspx');  
        PageMethods.AddFavorite(url, friendly, onSuccess, onError);  
}
```

Comment: Tried this but it did't help. It did complain about "preCondition", said it was not an allowed attribute.

Comment: What's the version of ASP.NET/VS/IIS that you're using?

Comment: .Net 4.5, VS 2017, IIS 7.5.

Comment: Did you get a 401 UnAuthorized exception while invoking the page method? - If so, try turning off the AutoRedirectMode property of FriendlyUrlSettings in the RouteConfig as follows:                      
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)  
        {  
            var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();  
            **settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;**  
            routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);  
        }

Comment: Perfect! That did the trick. The only think is that now all the pages have blah.aspx in URL instead of the friendly name (Instead of "Home", I have "default.aspx"). Is it possible to set redirect mode to off conditionally?

Comment: Have updated my answer that explains how to retain the friendly URLs! Please mark it as the answer if it helped you! :)

Comment: I added "using Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.Resolvers" and replaced "RegisterRoutes()" with your code and ran the app again. It is back to the same issue (displays page content in alert box).

Comment: Sorry, missed to inform you about the JS change that's required to explicitly add the '.aspx' extension to the page method. Please find the updated answer!

Comment: .net 4.6.1 same problem, somebody forget pagemethods to commit project template. Thanks @ashin

Comment: Related to the javascript set_path change, subsequent calls would continue to append ASPX to the path and fail after the first attempt. you need a check like this: if( PageMethods.get_path().indexOf(".aspx")==-1)

Answer (score 0):

add an onFailure method to see if it gets hit. (it might be required, but i'm not positive.) edit: i don't think it's required. i just copied your code and it works here.

have to ask, just to be sure: those js functions are inside script tags? (i guess so, if 'success' is getting hit. just checking.)

one more check: code behind using statement required: `using System.Web.Services;`.

Comment: I don't think it would make a difference. You see form code sample, i added "debugger" to JS functions; onSuccess gets hit and displays something but it is not the result from web method as I expect, but partial page source.

Comment: I think the fact that it displays partial page source in JS alert box (i.e. in alert(result)) is a clue. Why page source is stored in "result" parameter of onSuccess() function?

Comment: maybe a trace will find something. add `/trace.axd` to the end of the url in the browser and hit enter.

Comment: Thanks, I did that and it actually shows "Main/Default/AddFavorite" with status code of 200 (I believe it means Success) and "POST" as verb. The method (AddFavorite) is in file "/Main/Default.aspx.cs". It seems the method does get hit, even though the breakpoint I set in that method is not hit. Also, the method just returns one of its parameters (for testing) that is supposed to be displayed in alert box but instead it displays partial page source in alert box.

Comment: I also see this: Unhandled exception at line 6, column 97862 in http://localhost:51204/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'webServiceFailedNoMsg' of undefined or null reference occurred

Comment: just to see what happens, delete the script manager and add it again (with `EnablePageMethods="true"`). maybe something went screwy there.